# VS2010 - Listbox Shows "system._comobject" Instead of Values

Tags: vb.net, winforms, excel-interop

```
Private Sub CheckBox2_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CheckBox2.CheckedChanged
    Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
    Dim xlWorkBook As Excel.Workbook
    Dim xlWorkSheet As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim i As Integer = 3
    xlApp = New Excel.Application
    xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\JDoe\Documents\Ben's Project\Food.xlsx")
    xlWorkSheet = xlWorkBook.Worksheets("Revision Dates")
    If CheckBox2.Checked = True Then
        Panel2.Show()
        CheckBox1.Enabled = False
        ListBox1.Show()
        Label3.Show()
        'istBox1.Items.Add(xlWorkSheet.Range("A1", "A14").Value)
        Do

            ListBox1.Items.Add(xlWorkSheet.Cells(i, 1))
            i += 1
        Loop Until xlWorkSheet.Cells(i, 1).value = "01/01/01"
    Else
        Panel2.Hide()
        ListBox1.Hide()
        Label3.Hide()
        CheckBox1.Enabled = True
    End If
End Sub
```

I tick a checkbox on my form (checkbox2) and then listbox1 shows up. I have entered a list of dates in the "Revision Dates" worksheet, from A3 onwards. I want my code to read that column and transfer those values to the listbox. 
I do not receive any errors when I run the code however the listbox on my form does not show the dates (e.g. 01/01/2018) but rather "system._comobject"

Any suggestions?

Thank you.

Comment: Why are you adding the cell to the listbox instead of its value?

Comment: Cells have a lot of properties, add `.Value`

Answer (score 3):

```
ListBox1.Items.Add(xlWorkSheet.Cells(i, 1))
```

That's adding the `Range` object returned by the `Cells` member call. If you mean to add the cell's `Value`, then you need to be explicit about it, for I don't think .net interop honors default/implicit member calls the way VB6/VBA/COM does.

```
ListBox1.Items.Add(xlWorkSheet.Cells(i, 1).Value)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use CType to convert your object into an excel object.

```
Private Sub CheckBox2_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CheckBox2.CheckedChanged
    Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
    Dim xlWorkBook As Excel.Workbook
    Dim xlWorkSheet As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim i As Integer = 3
    xlApp = New Excel.Application
    xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\JDoe\Documents\Ben's Project\Food.xlsx")
    xlWorkSheet = xlWorkBook.Worksheets("Revision Dates")
    If CheckBox2.Checked = True Then
        Panel2.Show()
        CheckBox1.Enabled = False
        ListBox1.Show()
        Label3.Show()
        'istBox1.Items.Add(xlWorkSheet.Range("A1", "A14").Value)
        Do

            ListBox1.Items.Add(CType(xlWorkSheet.Cells(i, 1), excel.Range).Value))
            i += 1
        Loop Until CType(xlWorkSheet.Cells(i, 1), excel.Range).Value) = "01/01/01"
    Else
        Panel2.Hide()
        ListBox1.Hide()
        Label3.Hide()
        CheckBox1.Enabled = True
    End If
End Sub
```